# Прослушивание массива Stream'ов в Java

Tags: java, сокет, потоки-данных, epoll, android-bluetooth

Существует ли в **Java** какой-либо специфический механизм мультиплексирования событий ввода-вывода, подобный [`epoll`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll)?

*P.S. В частности меня интересует прослушка массива [`BluetoothSocket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html)'ов (**Android**).*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621783/is-there-epoll-equivalent-in-java

Comment: @Etki: да, я разумеется видел этот ответ ещё до того, как решил продублировать вопрос на русском, но во-первых он слишком сложный, для того, чтобы читать его через GoogleTranslate, а во-вторых там не приведено примеров использования этих `SelectableChannels`, и в ответе от старости умерла ссылка. Для них как будто нужно наследовать что-то особенное, такое, чего не наследуют Android'ные `BluetoothSocket`'ы.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621783/is-there-epoll-equivalent-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ - нет. Если программа в Java многосокетная, обычно создаються Thread'ы на каждое соединение. Java - многоплатформенная система, и не на всех платформах может быть аналог epoll.

PS.
Попробуй java.nio.channels.Selector, теоритичечки он должен работать и с Bluetooth соединениями.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что с `android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket` он полноценно не работает — только с `java.net.Socket`.